# How to add an entry into a Map without using the put() method

Tags: java

Do we have any other way to add an element into Map without using put() in Java? If there are other ways, how do we do it?

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("hi","HI");
```

How can we add without using put() in this case?

Comment: you mean with a shovel?

Comment: there exist a method called putAlll. But that is not exactly the same http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)

Comment: You can use the methods `replace` and `putIfAbsent` ... *if* you're using java 8.

Comment: You probably should not be using `Map` if you want other ways of adding an element.

Comment: If you're asking for `Map` literals (something like `Map<Integer, String> map = {1="Hi", 2="Hello"};`) the answer is that you just can't do that. Lots of tedious calls to `put` is unfortunately how you have to initialise a `Map` at the moment.

Comment: What's wrong with put()? Why do you want to avoid using it? Why don't you read the javadoc, which would answer this question?

Comment: You can specify initial content in the constructor. But internally it all boils down to some form of put, of course.

Answer (score 1):

`put` and `putAll` are the only two methods for adding new hash entries in Java. If you're looking for a Ruby or Python style way of doing it such as `hash['x'] = 'hello world';`, then you are going to need to use a JVM language like JRuby or Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change HashMap content without calling `put()` or other mutation methods. Probably, you are looking for *double brace initialization*. For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/2487403).